What’s it called when the last word of a page is repeated?
What’s it called when the last word of a page is repeated on the following page?
See, e.g. King Edward VIII’s statement of abdication (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:King_Edward%27s_Abdication_(11196393654).jpg)

(Just commenting so I can follow this…)

This question is similar to: What's the term used when the first word of one page is repeated at the end of the previous page?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
